# Unity resolving constructor with ICollection<IMyInterface> dependency

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm programming a rule engine. I have an interface `IRule` which many rules implement. Additionally, I have a `RuleExecutor` which get an `IEnumerable<IRule>` dependency injected.

I want Unity to inject an `IEnumerable<IRule>` with all bound implementations, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

This is my configuration:

```
container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleA>("a");
container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleB>("b");
container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleC>("c");
container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleD>("d");
container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleE>("e");
container.RegisterCollection<IRule>();

container.RegisterType<IRuleExecutor, RuleExecutor>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IEnumerable<IRule>)));
```

RegisterCollection is this:

```
public static class UnityExtensions
{
    public static void RegisterCollection<T>(this IUnityContainer container) where T : class
    {
        container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<T>>(new InjectionFactory(c => c.ResolveAll<T>()));
    }
}
```

I get following exception message when resolving:

> RuleExecutor does not have a constructor that takes the parameters ().

How is this possible with Unity?

Comment: Can you show the RuleExecutor class?

Comment: I think error is self explanatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity will inject all named instances into an `IEnumerable<T>` automatically. Here is a working example.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleA>("a");
        container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleB>("b");
        container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleC>("c");
        container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleD>("d");
        container.RegisterType<IRule, RuleE>("e");
        container.RegisterType<IRuleExecutor, RuleExecutor>();

        var executor = container.Resolve<IRuleExecutor>();
    }
}

public interface IRule { }
public class RuleA : IRule { }
public class RuleB : IRule { }
public class RuleC : IRule { }
public class RuleD : IRule { }
public class RuleE : IRule { }

public interface IRuleExecutor { }
public class RuleExecutor : IRuleExecutor
{
    public RuleExecutor(IEnumerable<IRule> rules)
    {
        // Rules RuleA through RuleE are injected here...
    }
}
```